# header has zero height, but logo shows ios react native

Tags: react-native

On ios, the header logo shows, but appears as if it is position: absolute because the header does not fill the space of the height provided.

Here is the header
[image: header with logo]

The top of the logo is also clipped.

Here are the navigation options I am using:

```
const defaultNavigationOptions = (customProps: any = {}) => () => {
    if (
        Platform.OS === "ios" &&
        typeof customProps.marginLeft !== "undefined"
    ) {
        customProps.marginLeft += 50;
    }

    let headerHeight = 50;
    if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
        headerHeight = 44;
    }

    return {
        cardStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#fff",
        },
        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: globalStyles.constants.defaultBGColor,
            borderBottomColor: globalStyles.constants.lightGrayColor3,
            borderBottomWidth: 1,
            height: headerHeight,
        },
        headerTitle: () => (
            <View
                style={{
                    height: headerHeight,
                    flex: 1,
                    flexDirection: "row",
                }}
            >
                <Image
                    fadeDuration={0}
                    style={{
                        alignSelf: "center",
                        flex: 1,
                        width: 200,
                        height: headerHeight,
                        resizeMode: "contain",
                        zIndex: 1,
                        overflow: "hidden",
                        ...customProps,
                    }}
                    source={require("./assets/new-logo-6-3.png")} // heracles3-large-dark10.png
                />
            </View>
        ),
    };
};
```

And it using SafeAreaProvider if that makes a difference

```
render() {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <SafeAreaProvider>
                <AppContainer
                    ref={(navRef: any) => {
                        if (navRef && navRef._navigation) {
                            api.setConfig(navRef._navigation);
                        }
                    }}
                />
            </SafeAreaProvider>
        </Provider>
    );
}
```

It works as expected on Android. Using `react-navigation-stack` v 2.10.4 (latest as of this writing). Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Can you share an image of how it looks on android?

Comment: The issue was adding `height` to `headerStyle` for some reason..

Answer (score 0):

The issue was including `height` in `headerStyle`.  I have no idea why this would break it. Removing this and adding width to the wrapping `headerTitle` `View` fixed it.